# How to use partial match on vscode-icons

Tags: visual-studio-code

I trying to add custom icons on vscode-icons.

Unfortunately my project file names have not extension naming rule.

They just end with '*Style.tsx' like 'ButtonStyle.tsx' or 'BoxStyle.tsx'

```
// this not work
    {
      "icon": "styled-components",
      "format": "png",
      "filenamesGlob": ["*Style", "*style"],
      "extensionsGlob": ["tsx", "ts"],
      "filename": true,
    }
```

I noticed that vscode-icons not support regex.

Is there any other way without renaming files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

vscode-icons does not support real globbing. I was just looking for the same thing and found
https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/issues/2459 where the author comments

> filenamesGlob and extensionsGlob are not to be used for glob expressions.

> Those two attributes are used in combination to produce multiple file extensions. Again, it's not the glob you think it is.

Apparently vsCode doesn't let icon theme extensions do real globbing (guess it's slow) so this extension has just done their own limited variant: They can only match strings after the dot.

So if you are prepared to rename your files from `ButtonStyle.tsx` and `LinkStyle.tsx`  to `Button.style.tsx` and `Link.style.tsx` you can target all files ending with `.style.tsx` via this rule

```
"vsicons.associations.files": [
  {
      "icon": "css",
      "filenamesGlob: ["style"],
      "extensionsGlob: ["tsx"],
  }
]
```

I guess fileNamesGlob matches the string after the first dot and extensionsGlob matches the string after the second dot.